# How can I get the average page load time of the page that takes longer to load using Google Analytics REST API?

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm trying to get the average page load time of the page that takes longer to load using Google Analytics REST API.
The following URL:

`https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3XXXXXXXX&start-date=2016-10-01&end-date=2017-11-30&metrics=ga%3APageLoadTime&dimensions=ga%3Adate`

Provides me the average page load time per day, but what I'm trying to get is the average page load time not for all the pages, but only for the page that takes longer to load. For the example that I'm providing, the URL will `return me 9.4` (Total average page load time for a day), while the number that I want to retrieve is `74.6s` (Average page load time for the page that takes longer to load).

[Google analytics site view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmdI0.png)

Any idea on how to do that? I also tried adding `ga:pagePath` as dimension, but it will return all the average page times of all the pages ones, and I only want to get the ones that takes longer.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried [sort](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#sort) parameter? Try sorting by pageLoadTime in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible to do this via a single call, to extract the longest load you need to add the page dimension and sort it desc.

https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3Axxxxxx&start-date=2016-10-01&end-date=2017-11-30&metrics=ga%3AavgPageLoadTime&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath&sort=-ga%3AavgPageLoadTime&max-results=1

Now you have to this day (i highly recommend you store this value on your own database and get this value from there),i think that you wanted to made a chart with this.

If i were to do this,i look for the Avg value, this metric can be better to determine medias, the highest one can be a single user that saw only a page and uses a very slow connection